# Can not allocate new socket, throwing invalid argument exception

Tags: c#, sockets, exception, networking, allocation

I created a new project and the single line of code is the allocation of a new socket:

```
Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

And it throws an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type system.net.sockets.socket exception
>   occurred in System32.DLL
>
> Additional information: An invalid argument was supplied

It also writes those codes: `0x80004005, ErrorCode: 10022`

Comment: That should work. Is there any pending updates to install? or you installed some updates and didn't restarted the PC ? If so restart and try again.

Comment: No updates and I restarted the cumputer already

Comment: Is there a network card in the computer? What operating system is this? This doesn't look like a problem in your code (unless you've copied it over wrong), so it might be a better fit for some other SE site. Is IPv4 active on the computer? It might be you've only got IPv6 available, for example.

Comment: I do have network card iha windows server 2008 r2 and ipv4 is enabled, what other she site you suggest?

Comment: Run application as administrator.

Comment: It doesn't work either

Comment: What is the exact context in which you are writing and running this code? Do you have an anti-virus or firewall installed? What is the exact, full stack trace of the exception? Please post [a good, complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: The code doesn't have any problem. That's the way you create a TCP socket. I think you have [system/OS]-specific problem. As other users suggested, check your ethernet card settings. I don't think it's matter of firewall. What happens if you set first parameter InterNetworkV6? What happens if you set last parameter as Udp?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope my late answer is still useful for others, who have the same issue.

I have had the same issues with several networking/socket examples and every searching (parameter combination mismatch?/Disconnect instead of Close/optional settings to reuse address or socket) did *NOT* fix it. This 'invalid argument' error message was misleading. Now, I figured this out:

**Most likely, you are also running the code in Visual Studio or the Executable (exe) directly on a network volume or share.** Even executed as an Administrator will not work.

When I copied the **executable/code project to a local volume** on my PC, all socket programs **worked well** (even without Administrator rights).

Probably, a change of your User Account Control (UAC) rights or your companies domain group policies could circumvent this issue.

Regards
F.J.

Comment: I was seeing this as well. This fixed my issue.

Comment: I had the same problem and this fixed the issue for me. Thanks - I wish I could upvote this twice.