# Can't reach the web from windows server

Tags: web, f#

I am trying to get a program to run at a clients server, and one thing I need to do is to do a webrequest to send an email notification.

Everything works locally, but not at the clients server, and I am not able to figure out why.

This is the exception (`Exception.GetType().Name: AggregateException`):

```
Exception: One or more errors occurred. (An invalid argument was supplied. (www.gstatic.com:80)) at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncResult`1.Commit() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\async.fs:line 391
at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.QueueAsyncAndWaitForResultSynchronously[a](CancellationToken token, FSharpAsync`1 computation, FSharpOption`1 timeout) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\async.fs:line 1042
at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.RunSynchronously[T](CancellationToken cancellationToken, FSharpAsync`1 computation, FSharpOption`1 timeout) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\async.fs:line 1070
at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync.RunSynchronously[T](FSharpAsync`1 computation, FSharpOption`1 timeout, FSharpOption`1 cancellationToken) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\async.fs:line 1365
at Program.checkForInternetConnection(FSharpFunc`2 log)
```

The inner exception (no addinitonal information when walking the inner exception recursively):

```
InnerException: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An invalid argument was supplied. (www.gstatic.com:80)
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10022): An invalid argument was supplied.
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(AddressFamily , SocketType , ProtocolType )
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(SocketType , ProtocolType )
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String , Int32 , HttpRequestMessage , Boolean , CancellationToken )
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String , Int32 , HttpRequestMessage , Boolean , CancellationToken )
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage , Boolean , CancellationToken )
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage , Boolean , CancellationToken )
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage )
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken )
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage , Boolean , CancellationToken )
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage , Boolean , Boolean , CancellationToken )
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage , Boolean , CancellationToken )
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage , HttpCompletionOption , CancellationTokenSource , Boolean , CancellationTokenSource , CancellationToken )
```

And this is the code in question

```
type Async with
    static member Await task =
        task |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
    
let client = new HttpClient()
    
let checkForInternetConnection log =
    let url = "http://www.gstatic.com/generate_204"
    try
        let response = client.GetAsync(url) |> Async.Await
        let status = response.StatusCode
        log $"Has internet connection, could reach {url}. Expecting status code NoContent, was: {status.ToString()}."
        true
    with
        | :? Exception as e -> 
            log $"Exception: {e.Message} {e.StackTrace}"
            false
```

I worked when we ran it on a local server, but not on the file server.

I also for .net version, and got this back, so I guess .net 3:

```
PS C:\Users\500000tova-adm> Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -Recurse | Get-ItemProperty -Name version -EA 0 | Where { $_.PSChildName -Match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} | Select PSChildName, version

PSChildName Version
----------- -------
v2.0.50727 2.0.50727.4927
v3.0 3.0.30729.4926
Windows Communication Foundation 3.0.4506.4926
Windows Presentation Foundation 3.0.6920.4902
v3.5 3.5.30729.4926
Client 4.7.03190
Full 4.7.03190
```

Google is giving me nothing, and I'm quite stuck

Comment: Can you check the `Exception.InnerException` property? I suspect it might contain more useful information. You might even want a helper function that walks the inner exceptions recursively in order to get to the root cause.

Comment: @BrianBerns I updated the question with the first inner exception. I will update again when I create something that can walk it recursively

Comment: Interesting. Do you know what version of .NET is running on the server? And is it Windows or Linux?

Comment: One other question: Are you perhaps running the program from a network volume or share? If so, try running it from a local share instead. (See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917402/can-not-allocate-new-socket-throwing-invalid-argument-exception).)

Comment: @BrianBerns I ahve updated the description with the .net version. It worked on a local server, not on the file server, so the problem seems to be there. I trying to figure out if we can use the local server or not. I included the .net version in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve this, but in the end we got it to work by running it from a different location.